# D3,js on mouse event CLICK appending only the first image from data set

Tags: image, d3.js, mouseevent

I want to append 1 image at the time to an DIV element by clicking on the bars in the bar chart, but I get only the first image. If I use enter() then I get all images exept the first one.

```
var data = [{"val": 5,  "imgsrc": "http://placehold.it/300x100"},
        {"val": 40, "imgsrc": "a1.png"},
        {"val": 50, "imgsrc": "http://placehold.it/200x100"},
        {"val": 60, "imgsrc": "http://placehold.it/150x100"},
        {"val": 80, "imgsrc": "http://placehold.it/100x100"}];  

var width = 500;
var height = 500;

var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, 100])
                .range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, 100])
                .range(["red", "blue"]);    

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(widthScale)
                .ticks(5);

var container = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");

var bars = container.selectAll("rect")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("width", function(d){ return widthScale(d.val) })
                    .attr("height", 30)
                    .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.val) })
                    .attr("y", function(d, i){ return i * 50 });

var setEvents = bars          
                .on( 'click', function (d) {
                    d3.select("#tool").style("opacity", 1.0); 
                    d3.select("#tool").html(d.imgsrc); 
                    d3.select('#tool')
                        .data(data) 
                        //.enter()
                        .append('img')
                        .attr('src', function(d, i) {return d.imgsrc;});               
           });

container.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0, 400)")
                .call(axis);
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Is `#tool` your DIV? I What do you want to do? To show only one image at a time, and replace it with a new one? `enter()` is used to bind data with elements. I'm not sure what you want to do. If you want to bind many images, then call `.selectAll("#tool img")` before `.data()`, and keep the `.enter()`, which will append as many `img` you need to bind the data.

Comment: Thanx for your reaction. Yes, #tool is DIV, and I would like to show only one image at a time, and replace it with a new one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array variable `images` to hold selected image urls. Update the array on click of bars. You can create the image elements as shown below.

```
var images = [];

var setEvents = bars
  .on('click', function(d) {
    d3.select("#tool").style("opacity", 1.0);
   // d3.select("#tool").html(d.imgsrc);
    images.push(d.imgsrc);
    d3.select('#tool')
      .selectAll("img")
      .data(images)
      .enter()
      .append('img')
      .attr("width", 50)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr('src', function(d, i) {
        return d
      });
  });
```

**Working Code Snippet:**

```js
var data = [{
  "val": 5,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/gray/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}, {
  "val": 40,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/color/005500/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}, {
  "val": 50,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}, {
  "val": 60,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/color/550055/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}, {
  "val": 80,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/color/990000/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}];

var width = 500;
var height = 500;

var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range(["red", "blue"]);

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(widthScale)
  .ticks(5);

var container = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");

var bars = container.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return widthScale(d.val)
  })
  .attr("height", 30)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.val)
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 50
  });

var images = [];

var setEvents = bars
  .on('click', function(d) {
    d3.select("#tool").style("opacity", 1.0);
   // d3.select("#tool").html(d.imgsrc);
    images.push(d.imgsrc);
    d3.select('#tool')
      .selectAll("img")
      .data(images)
      .enter()
      .append('img')
      .attr("width", 50)
      .attr("height", 50)
      .attr('src', function(d, i) {
        return d
      });
  });

container.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, 400)")
  .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="tool"></div>
```

**Edit:**

```js
var data = [{
  "val": 5,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/gray/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}, {
  "val": 40,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/color/005500/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}, {
  "val": 50,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/black/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}, {
  "val": 60,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/color/550055/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}, {
  "val": 80,
  "imgsrc": "http://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/color/990000/square-rounded-xxl.png"
}];

var width = 500;
var height = 500;

var widthScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range([0, width]);

var color = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, 100])
  .range(["red", "blue"]);

var axis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(widthScale)
  .ticks(5);

var container = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)");

var bars = container.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return widthScale(d.val)
  })
  .attr("height", 30)
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.val)
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return i * 50
  });


var setEvents = bars
  .on('click', function(d) {
    d3.select("#tool").style("opacity", 1.0);           
    d3.select('#tool').selectAll("img").remove();
    d3.select('#tool')
       .append('img')
       .attr("width", 50)
       .attr("height", 50)
       .attr('src',d.imgsrc);
  });

container.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, 400)")
  .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="tool"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gilsha. It works great. Do you have sugestion how can I show only one image at a time, and replace it with a new one?

Comment: Edited in answer. You can implement it easily by following the new code snippet.

Comment: Thank you once more Gilsha, for beeing so kind to answer my questions. Everything works perfect. You helped me a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help you.